# Search by class in Nokogiri nodeset

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I got the name of a CSS class from a Nokogiri node. Now I want to find all the nodes that also have the same class attached.

I don't know which HTML tag the element that I'm looking for has, and how deep it is. All i know is what class to search for.

I have already tried:

```
doc.xpath("//*[contains(@class, #{css})]")
```

But this seems to return WAY too many elements.

Also I have tried:

```
doc.xpath("//*[@class, #{css}]")
```

and this returns nothing.

I want to get the elements that contain that class, not every element that surrounds an element with that class.

Is it possible to do this with Nokogiri?

Comment: I haven't used Nokogiri for a while, but won't doc.css('my-class') or doc.search('my-class') do what you want? Nokogiri works nicely with CSS selectors, and you only need to resort to XPath for advanced matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the class name is stored into `class_name`, I think that

```
doc.xpath("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' #{class_name} ')]")
```

is what you're looking for.

This will match all the elements that contain `class_name` into their classes, ie if `class_name` is 'box', then it will match both elements like `div class="box"` and elements like `div class="box left"`

If you only want to match elements like `div class="box"` ie that have only one class and that class is the one you're looking for, then you could use this:

```
doc.xpath("//*[@class=\"#{class_name}\"]")
```

Comment: doc.xpath("//*[@class=\"#{class_name}\"]") was exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: @egwspiti thanks for this. Could you maybe explain what exactly does the first code sample do? Why do you need `normalize-space`?

Answer (score 7):

As I said in my comment, `.css()` or `.search()` can find all elements of a given class.

Here's an example from a scraper I wrote a while ago. It finds the only `.content` div on the page (`at()` will select the first element only), and then finds all `.col` divs inside it. Then it loops through them and prints the title.

```
content = page.at('.content')
content.css('.col').each do |col|
    puts col.at('h5').text
end
```

Comment: this is a much better solution!

Comment: I don't know how often I have done this, but I forgot to prefix the class name I was looking for with a dot. Thanks for the example.